# how to download 'generated source' from web developer toolbar in firefox

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, toolbar

I want my java program to see the 'generated source' of a webpage, in Web Developer Toolbar:    https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ 
in FireFox, found under the 'view source' menu, as opposed to simply the actual html source which regularly returns itself through java networking:

```
HttpURLconnection.getInputStream();
```

Can a java program do this, or at least delegate the task to another application on the same computer, written in something else (javascript) which gets embedded in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

[selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) should be able to do that. i used it a long time ago so i don't remember how exactly. but it's basically a browser plugin and some server code which communicates with the plugin. you can communicate via a java driver with the server and control the browser content and also get all the data from the DOM.

EDIT:
depending if a "real" browser is not necessary you can also use [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is basically a gui less browser in java.

Comment: selenium looks good, i think htmlunit wouldnt work, especially if some of the generated html used info on browser plugins or a dom which got modified based on events

Answer (score 1):

If by "generated source", you mean the full DOM of a working web page, including elements that have been added, removed or modified by javascript in that page, then there is no way to do this without using a full browser engine to first render the page and then some sort of communication with that page or engine to give you the HTML for the generated page.

You could not do this with java alone.

You could put javascript in the web page itself which would fetch the innerHTML of the whole web page after it was fully generated and then use an ajax call to send that to your server.  You would have to stay within the limitations of the same-origin-policy (which doesn't allow you to make ajax calls to domains other than where the host web page came from).

You could also find some server-side rendering engine that could do the same on the server side that your java application could use/communicate with.

Comment: what about from the client side?